# Centering <ul> element with inline list

Tags: css, list, centering

I'm a bit embarrassed to ask about this, but I'm struggling with centering a UL element inside a DIV. The UL block contains inline LIs.

This is the NavMenu on this website: http://dev.gratefulhearttherapy.org/

I've tried text-align:center and margin:auto to both the UL element and its parent DIV#headerNav and DIV.custom. None worked.

```
<div id="headerNav">
<div class="custom">
<ul id="mega-menu-77" class="mega-menu" style="display:none;">
<li class="nav-selected nav-path-selected top-level-nav first il-1"><a class="nav-selected nav-path-selected pl-1" href="/" accesskey="H">Home</a></li>
<li class="top-level-nav il-72"><a href="/services/psychotherapy/" class="pl-72" accesskey="S">Services</a><ul class='sub_menu pid-72'><li class=" il-88"><a href="/services/psychotherapy/" class="pl-88" accesskey="P">Psychotherapy</a></li>
<li...> ... </li>
<li...> ... </li>
<li...> ... </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It would be complicated to copy the CSS, so here is the direct file: http://dev.gratefulhearttherapy.org/index.php/tools/css/themes/gratefulheart/typography-new2.css though you'd have a better sense of it using Firebug or Chrome Inspector.

Thanks a lot for you figure it out or can lead me to the solution!!

Olivier

Comment: Hello. What are you trying to center? The sub-menu choices under the main menu items? From the mouse over effects it looks like you have some space in the div to the right of the choices.

Comment: did you try margin-left for the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.custom ul.mega-menu li`, change `float: left` to `display: inline-block`.

The `li`s will then be centered, thanks to `text-align: center` which you have on the parent `ul`.

You'll also need to add `display: block` to `.custom ul.mega-menu li .sub li`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it created another problem. The navigation menu is centered but the dropdown menu for the menu "Services" appears too much on the left (unlike the one for "About Us" which appears as expected below its parent menu). Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a block element, try this:

```
width:980px;
margin:0 auto;
```

`980px` can be changed to any value.

Also, don't forget to clear the float (look for "clearfix" on Google).